# EF Core, disable foreign key column name generation

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a tables/C# classes like below;

**Book** (C# class = MyStoreBook)

```
Id
Title
Tags
```

**BookTags** (C# class = MyStoreBookTag)

```
Id
BookId (Foreign Key)
Name
```

When I run following query via EF Core:

```
FromSqlRaw('select * from BookTags where bookid = @bookid')
```

I am getting an error

> The required column 'MyStoreBookId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

But I don't want EF to generate FK navigation property names, I just want it to make straight data binding with column names.

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Navigation property and FK property are different things. FK property is mapped to a real database table column like any other primitive data property, thus cannot be "disabled". You just have incorrect mapping (remember EF Core is a OR**Mapper**), causing EF Core to think that table contains column 'MyStoreBookId' instead of the actual 'BookId'. That's the actual problem you need to fix. How to do that depends on how your model class `MyStoreBookTag` looks like. Since you didn't include it in the post, we can't give you a concrete answer/hint.

Comment: If you scaffold your c# classes from the db, it'll work out.. ;)

Comment: @IvanStoev C# classes has same properties names as tables. I want to achieve 1-1 mapping, but EF Core expects select statement to have concrete column name `MyStoreBookId` which I don't want. That stored procedure might be used from DB providers, and I did not want to include generated names in it.

Comment: Apparently the classes do not have the same properties (or to say it differently, have additional navigation properties) as the database tables, otherwise EF Core won't expect column named 'MyStoreBookId'. As I said in the previous comment, you haven't mapped your classes and their relationships properly. Put your **classes** and relevant fluent configuration (if any) *in the question* if you want to get a solution.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. You were correct, I was confused with navigation/foreign key bindings. I found a similar answer in another question and posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected issue by adding `ForeignKey` attribute to `Book` class. I borrowed the answer from: [The required column 'CustomerId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888517/the-required-column-customerid-was-not-present-in-the-results-of-a-fromsql-o)

```
Book (C# class = MyStoreBook)   
Id
[ForeignKey(nameof(BookTags))]
Tags
Title
```